# Why am I getting 'Heap Corruption'?

Tags: c++, heap-corruption

Please don't crucify me for this one. I decided it might be good to use a char* because the string I intended to build was of a known size. I am also aware that if timeinfo->tm_hour returns something other than 2 digits, things are going to go badly wrong. That said, when this function returns VIsual Studio goes ape at me about HEAP CORRUPTION. What's going wrong? (Also, should I just use a stringbuilder?)

```
void cLogger::_writelogmessage(std::string Message)
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm* timeinfo = 0;

    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

    char* MessageBuffer = new char[Message.length()+11];
    char* msgptr = MessageBuffer;

    _itoa(timeinfo->tm_hour, msgptr, 10);
    msgptr+=2;

    strcpy(msgptr, "::");
    msgptr+=2;

    _itoa(timeinfo->tm_min, msgptr, 10);
    msgptr+=2;

    strcpy(msgptr, "::");
    msgptr+=2;

    _itoa(timeinfo->tm_sec, msgptr, 10);
    msgptr+=2;

    strcpy(msgptr, " ");
    msgptr+=1;

    strcpy(msgptr, Message.c_str());

    _file << MessageBuffer;

    delete[] MessageBuffer;
}
```

Comment: Seems like you are forgetting the NUL at the end of the string.  Off by one.

Comment: @jrockway Won't Message.c_str() add the null character?

Comment: `/me readies nails and hammer`

Comment: Like the answer below says, sure, it adds the NUL character.  But you didn't allocate any memory to store it, and it just overwrites some other data in memory.  "Heap corruption", if you will.

Comment: Once you've got the length right, you could also use strfttime and/or sscanf.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to allocate one more byte, since `.length` of a `string` returns its length without the terminating NUL, for which you also need space in the `char*`.

I.e. suppose `Message.length()` returns 10. You allocate 21 bytes. Copy 11 bytes into the buffer, then copy the message, which needs 10 bytes + one for NUL. Total: 22 bytes, and you only have 21 allocated.

Comment: @Michael: his last call is a `strcpy`, which *does* place a NUL at the end

Answer (score 3):

This

```
char* MessageBuffer = new char[Message.length()+11];
```

should be

```
char* MessageBuffer = new char[Message.length()+12];
```

Because you are adding `11` additional char to the buffer:

```
2 for hr
2 for ::
2 for min
2 for ::
2 for sec
1 for " "
```

you need one additional to for the terminating `null` char.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the size of `MessageBuffer` needs to be increased by one.

However, rather than dealing with the raw char buffer in that way, you could just stream the time information directly to `_file` without putting it into an intermediate string first.  If you want it in an intermediate string for some reason, I would suggest that you make use of the `ostringstream` class.

```
void writelogmessage(std::string Message)
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm* timeinfo = 0;

    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream<<
        timeinfo->tm_hour<<"::"<<
        timeinfo->tm_min<<"::"<<
        timeinfo->tm_sec<<" "<<
        Message;

    _file<<stream.str();
}
```